# Recursion error Python

Tags: python, recursion

I wrote a little bit code try to search a word in a list.
It's not the final version and basically it can't do anything yet.
However, I don't understand what was wrong with the code:

```
def findword (word, t):
    t.sort()
    midword = t[len(t)/2]
    midindex = len(t)/2
    if word > midword:
        del t[:midindex]
        findword (word, t)
    elif word < midword:
        del t[midindex+1:]
        findword (word, t)
    elif word == midword:
        return t
    else:
        return None

mydic=['apple','banana','peach','pear','melon','lemon','grape','berry']
mydic1 = findword('apple', mydic)
```

I got a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in cmp` error when tried to search `apple` and when I search the other words in the list, it returns empty list.

Please help me figure out what was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: You need more debugging print/logging statements, which would make it fairly obvious what's going wrong.

Comment: Also, instead of modifying the list you're searching through, only modify the current index and the upper and lower bounds where to search. Google 'binary search' if stuck.

Comment: OP: slightly off-topic, but if you're not in Python2 you've got a scary line in there that should use `__floordiv__` instead of `__truediv__`!!

Comment: @Noelkd I think he's using the layman definition of "dictionary" in his variable. It's a list of words :)

Comment: ..that will teach me for being a smart arse thanks @AdamSmith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this code segment:

```
    elif word < midword:
        del t[midindex+1:]
        findword (word, t)
```

In your code, you will come to a point that the list is reduced to just two elements, that is:

```
t == ['apple', 'banana']
```

In which case, take a look at the following interactive session:

```
In [15]: t = ['apple', 'banana']

In [16]: midindex = len(t)/2

In [17]: midindex
Out[17]: 1

In [18]: t[midindex+1:]
Out[18]: []

In [19]: del t[midindex+1:]

In [20]: t
Out[20]: ['apple', 'banana']
```

Notice that in line 19, you deleted nothing, `t` remains the same, then you called `findword` with the same list and run into infinite recursion until you run out of stack space. You should redesign your code to overcome this problem.

Another problem I see is you simply called `findword` recursively, but did not make use of the return value. Instead of:

```
    elif word < midword:
        del t[midindex+1:]
        findword (word, t)
```

you should do:

```
    elif word < midword:
        del t[midindex+1:]
        return findword (word, t)
```

## Additional Suggestions

- Do not put the `t.sort()` inside the `findword` function. Sorting could be expensive, so you should only do it once, outside of `findword`.
- As others pointed out, it is a bad practice to modify the list, instead redesign your code not to do that
- If this is not a homework or exercise, I suggest to use a `set` if you want fast look-up
- Python has a library module called `bisect` which will do binary search.

Comment: Thanks Hai! Your answer is exactly what I'm looking for. Now I understand why it keeps calling itself and causes overflow.

Answer (score 2):

### Implementation of Binary Search

First of all, recursion is yucky. Avoid that if you can -- it can cause these kinds of MaxRecursion errors in very huge search spaces when you're unlucky.

Let's switch this to iterative, and see what we can do:

```
def binary_search(lst, word):
    new_lst = sorted(lst) # so we only do this once
    return _binary_search(new_lst, word, start=0, end=len(new_lst))

def _binary_search(lst, word, start, end):
    while end - start > 0: # technically this is just while end-start but...
        pivot = (start + end) // 2 # floordiv!
        pivot_element = lst[pivot]
        if word > pivot_element:
            start = pivot + 1
        elif word < pivot_element:
            end = pivot
        else: # word == pivot_element
            return word
    else: return None

>>> my_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'peach', 'pear', 'melon', 'lemon', 'grape', 'berry']
>>> print(binary_search(my_list, "strawberry"))
None
>>> print(binary_search(my_list, "pear"))
"pear"
```

Comment: Great idea of adding `first` and `last` as function argument. It doesn't modify the list and still narrower the search space within each recursion. Thanks!

Comment: @homerMeng thanks. I don't think I'd ever actually built a binary search engine before, so it was nice to flex my algorithmic muscle

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to search for a word in a list, you can do this--

```
mydic=['apple','banana','peach','pear','melon','lemon','grape','berry']

inputword = 'apple'
if inputword in mydic:
    print('yes it is in the list')
else:
    print('no it is not')
```

Comment: OP is trying to implement a recursive binary search. I'm sure they know how to test for membership :)

Answer (score 0):

You cant change your dictonary in run time as you are doing.
And in your code you do not have return in you recursion calls.

```
def findword (word, t):
   for i in t:
      if i == word:
         return i
```

Or if you still prefer use binary search:

```
def findword (word, t):
    t.sort()
    return findword_aux(word, t, 0, len(t)-1)

def findword_aux(word, array, first, last):
    midindex = (first + last) / 2 
    midword = array[midindex]
    if last - first == 1:
        return None
    if word == midword:
        return  midword
    elif word > midword:
        return findword_aux (word, array, midindex+1, last)
    elif word < midword:
        return findword_aux (word, array, first, midindex-1)

def run_tests():
    test1()
    test2()

def test1():
    mydic=['apple','banana','peach','pear','melon','lemon','grape','berry'] 
    result = findword('apple', mydic)
    if result == 'apple':
        print 'test1 pass'
    else:
        print 'test1 error'

def test2():
    mydic=['apple','banana','peach','pear','melon','lemon','grape','berry'] 
    result = findword('pinapple', mydic)
    if result == None:
        print 'test2 pass'
    else:
        print 'test2 error'
```

Comment: `findword_aux` will return `None` if one of your search spaces is exactly one, but that element is exactly the target.

Comment: Adam was right. I'm testing your code and see what should be the fix. Thanks anyway!